# Passing trackable EF Entity to WCF service, using proxies

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

I'm currently sending my entities from WCF to client with no problems. The issue is that when I send one given entity back to WCF (the very same reference since its creation on client), the code `Context.Entry(entity).State` returns `Detached`.

If I make an inspection on `Context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` I see that my tracked entities are there, but they do not seem to be "reference related" to the one I received from client.

Any suggestions? I'd like to use the very same reference all the way through `WCF -> Client -> WCF`.

Comment: Why aren't you using DTOs? And what's wrong with simply re-attaching? This is the same problem you'd have if you used MVC and sent it to the client and back as a view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, you're going to have a disconnect that's pretty much unavoidable. EF is creating a proxy class that isn't part of your `DataContract` therefore the supplemental tracking data is lost in the [un]serialization process.

However, the good news is it's very easy to re-attach the entity using something like the following:

```
[OperationContract]
void Update(Entity entity)
{
    db.Set<Entity>().Attach(entity)
    // carry on
}
```

However, I would look into using Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) and stop sending your actual entities over the wire anyways. Your data may be simple, but in the long run it'll save you time on versioning, security, etc. There are also libraries like AutoMapper that make the conversion very simple. e.g.

```
// Example EF model
[Table("Users")]
class UserEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Password { get; set; }
}

// Example DTO model
[DataContract]
class UserDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    // No need to send Password over the wire.
    // Let's keep things a bit more secure.
}
```

Then bind:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserEntity,UserDto>()
  .ForMember(d => d.Id, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
  .ForMember(d => d.UserName, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.UserName))
  .ForSourceMember(s => d.Password, m => m.Ignore())
.ReverseMap()
  .ForMember(d => d.Id, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
  .ForMember(d => d.UserName, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.UserName))
  .ForMember(d => d.Password, m => m.Ignore());
// Confirm we have everything configured correctly.
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Then, in practice:

```
UserDto userDto = /* incoming model */
UserEntity user = Mapper.Map<UserEntity>(userDto);
db.Set<UserEntity>().Attach(user);
// carry on
```

Comment: When the command `db.Set<Entity>().Attach(entity)` runs I receive:

Attaching an entity of type 'AtcManagerCommon.Models.Employee' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values.

Comment: Then use `db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Updated;` May have skimmed a few parts for brevity, but there's a complete write up on attaching here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: The problem is that when I first created the service and ran `GetEntityByKey(int key)`, the `Context` added the returned entity to its `ChangeTracker`. If I attach this very entity with this key when it is sent back with `Update(Entity entity)`, I'll have duplicated values.
If I detach the former from the `ChangeTracker` and attach the new one, I believe that everything related to navigation properties will become a mess.

Nevertheless, I'll take a look into DTO. I don't think it solves my current problem, though.

Comment: I assume you're specifying `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession` on your ServiceBehavior? -- You can also grab the entity and update its values based on what's already in the tracker: `db.Entry(trackedEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity)`

Comment: `db.Entry(trackedEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity)` is what saved my life!
I suggest that you edit your answer and add this important part on it.

Besides, my `InstanceContextMode` is currently "PerSession" (default). I use a couple transactions between client and server in the same service channel. Any problems with that?

Comment: Nope, though I don't know what you're going for either. If it works for you, go with it. Just wondered why EF still knew about the entity between calls (I assumed it was (still) PerSession.)